# swift 画像以外をタッチするとエラーが出てしまう。

Tags: ios, swift

myImageAという名前の画像をタッチするとカウント（scoreNum)が下がっていきそれ以外はカウントが上がっていくコードなのですが、画像以外（何もないところ。背景などの真っ白なところ）をタッチするとクラッシュしてしまいます。

その時 `let touchedImageView = touch!.view as! UIImageView`の部分にエラーがあるとのことなのですが、自分では解決できず質問いたしました。

どのように書き換えればいいでしょうか？
コードも直して書いていただけるとありがたいです。

背景は  `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()`で白くしています。

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
　　　　let touch = touches.first as UITouch?
     // タッチしたUIImageViewを取得
     let touchedImageView = touch!.view as! UIImageView
　　　　
　　　　if touchedImageView.image == myImageA {
     　　　　scoreNum--
          return
　　　　 }
      else {
      　　　　scoreNum++
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

示されている`let touchedImageView = touch!.view as! UIImageView`では`as!` を使って`touch!.view`をUIImageViewへ強制的にキャストしようとしており、そのキャストが出来ない場合（touch!.viewがUIViewの場合など）にクラッシュしているだけだと思います。

`as?`を使いキャストが失敗するとnilを返すようにし、かつ`if let`のOptional Bindingを使いnilでなければ処理を実行する条件文とすれば、とりあえず期待する動作をするのではないでしょうか？

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch?
    // タッチしたUIImageViewを取得
    if let touchedImageView = touch!.view as? UIImageView {

        if touchedImageView.image == myImageA {
            scoreNum--
            return
        } else {
  　        scoreNum++
        }
    } else {
  　    scoreNum++
    }
}
```

（どのようにOptionalを扱うのが最適かについては質問の答えではないと判断するため、とりあえず期待する動作をすることだけを目的としています）